# Border-radius breaking on font awesome?

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I am trying to add `border` and then `border-radius` on font-awesome icon but its displaying black holes on top and bottom. Here is the image of issue

[image: icon]

i here is my CSS code

```css
i.fa{
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #ccc;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

Comment: you cant use border-radius for background images.

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai Ponnukalai is there any icon in circle ??? other then font-awesome

Comment: you should try padding and margin

Comment: are you trying for circular icons?

Comment: maybe so - http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/ybpft9x2/

Comment: @Dmitriy buddy your code not working over here just work in jsfiddle why??

Comment: @Ashesh yeah i need circular icons

Comment: check my answer, it's similar to what Meysam has done. I have changed the icon color to black and their circular background to white with added explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by stacking other icons over the `fa-circle` icon to make them look circular in shape. Also the color can be inverted using the class `fa-inverse`.

> To stack multiple icons, use the fa-stack class on the parent, the
>   fa-stack-1x for the regularly sized icon, and fa-stack-2x for the
>   larger icon. fa-inverse can be used as an alternative icon color. You
>   can even throw larger icon classes on the parent to get further
>   control of sizing.
>
> -http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/examples/

over here (smaller) social icons are stacked over the (larger) `fa-circle` icon. also note that these are not the square version ie. don't use `facebook-square`, `twitter-square` etc

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}
input {
  background-color: #E88080;
  border: 0px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div>
  <input type="text" />
  <span class="fa-stack">
    <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x fa-inverse"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-search fa-stack-1x"></i>
  </span>
</div>
<div class="social">
  <span class="fa-stack">
  <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x fa-inverse"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-linkedin fa-stack-1x"></i>
</span>
  <span class="fa-stack">
  <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x fa-inverse"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-facebook fa-stack-1x"></i>
</span>
  <span class="fa-stack">
  <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x fa-inverse"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-stack-1x"></i>
</span>
  <span class="fa-stack">
  <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x fa-inverse"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-instagram fa-stack-1x"></i>
</span>
</div>
<h6 style="color:white; font-family:monospace">Note that if you have ad blocking active on this page, you won't be able to see the icons.</h6>
```

Answer (score 5):

you must put this element in code

```
overflow: hidden;
```

try this it may works

```
<span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
  <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-flag fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
</span>
```

http://fontawesome.io/examples/

Answer (score 0):

Bilal, as Suresh said, you cannot use border-radius on font-awesome because font-awesome is a collection of SVG images. You can however try filling in the circle with a white background, making the text smaller and making the font black.

```
body
{
    background: #000;
}

.button
{
    background: #FFF;
    color: #000;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 20px;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
```

Result: http://jsfiddle.net/7rjkwqft/

Comment: i need to change icon's background to white and text to black